# Advanced unique constrant with MySQL

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

Boiled down to the essence of my problem I have a MySQL table (InnoDB) with a DATETIME field and I need to implement a duplicate check that does not allow the same date, down to the hour, to be used more than once (eg. only one row with 2013-07-18 13:xx:xx).

My first question then is, if there any way to enforce this in the MySQL database itself?

Otherwise my approach would be along the lines of:

1. Lock the table for both read and writes (to avoid the
2. Make a SELECT query to verify I can insert the new row
3. Insert it
4. Unlock the table again

I really dislike this solution - any suggestions on how to do this without having to lock the table would be appreciated.

Comment: Store the date and time components separately to different columns and create unique constraint based on that? You just require DATE part paired with hour, I'd save the entire datetime to 1 column, date part to another and hour component to third column. Unique key on (date, hour) will give you what you need.

Comment: @N.B.: You'd also need a trigger to guarantee the datetime column always matched other two columns.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' that makes no sense, sorry. If you care to elaborate, please do so.

Comment: @N.B.: Imagine inserting a tuple like {2013-01-01 08:00, 2013-01-01, 8}. Updating the first column to '2013-03-31 17:00' corrupts the data, but doesn't affect the unique constraint. You need a trigger to make sure that updates like that leave the data in a consistent state.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' - so you're furthering the problem and talking about updating the record, avoiding the initial problem of creating the constraint? You don't *need* a trigger, it's nice to have to ensure the integrity, I agree about that, but I just mentioned having a tuple of {datetime, date, hour} as a nice to have, what's relevant is only {date, hour}. This can be achieved without the datetime component, thus removing the need for trigger.

Comment: How much easier would that be with a modern DBMS that supports function based indexes....

Comment: @N.B.: No, I'm saying that a solution that allows a tuple like {2013-03-31 17:00, 2013-01-01, 8} is not a solution.

Comment: You wouldn't _have_ to store the data redundantly; you could simply drop the "complete" datetime column and have columns date, hour, minute, second, which can be concatenated according to the application's needs. Performance will be degraded, of course, but redundancy is avoided. That's the tradeoff.

Comment: @stef77: Although that *sounds* simple, it's not the whole story. To keep hours like 75 out of the database, you need another table for valid hours, and a foreign key constraint. And you need another table for valid minutes (same reason), and yet another for valid seconds (same reason). And you'd probably also build a view to hide the implementation. But it would work.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': Very true. At first, I just didn't like the idea of using triggers (I generally don't), but come to think of it, splitting up the time values is rather ugly and a source for all other kinds of mess. Too bad you can't specify the length of the index on datetime columns like on varchar columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple, declarative way to do this in MySQL. But you can create a shadowing column, and use triggers to keep the data consistent. This assumes that "ts" (below) can be any valid timestamp, but that you want only one of them per hour.

```
create table test (
   ts datetime not null,
   ts_uniq char(13) not null,
   unique (ts_uniq)
);
```

The column "ts_uniq" is the shadowing column. It will hold strings like '2013-01-01 08'.

```
create trigger bef_ins_test 
before insert on test
for each row
set new.ts_uniq = date_format(new.ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H');
```

You'll need a similar trigger that executes before updates.

```
create trigger bef_upd_test 
before update on test
for each row
set new.ts_uniq = date_format(new.ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H');
```

When you insert values for "ts", the shadowing column is automatically set correctly.

```
insert into test (ts) values ('2013-01-01 08:35:33');
select * from test;

ts                   ts_uniq
--
2013-01-01 08:35:33  2013-01-01 08
```

Trying to insert a slightly different value fails correctly, raising error code 1062 (duplicate entry).

```
insert into test (ts) values ('2013-01-01 08:47:13');
```

If you update the existing timestamp, the BEFORE UPDATE trigger keeps the column "ts_uniq" consistent.

```
update test
set ts = '2013-01-01 17:42:42';

select * from test;

ts                   ts_uniq
--
2013-01-01 17:42:42  2013-01-01 17
```

Trying to independently update "ts_uniq" won't raise an error, but it won't change the row, either.

```
update test
set ts_uniq = '2013-12-31 18';

select * from test;

ts                   ts_uniq
--
2013-01-01 17:42:42  2013-01-01 17
```